# Scrape Site With Incremental IDs

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a site in the following format:

http://www.domain.com/membership/member_zoom.php?value

value starts at 1000 and stops around 15,000

Here is a sample of the source:

```
<h1>Member Information</h1>


<h2>Company Name</h2>
<p>Address<br />
More Address<br />
City<br />
State<br />
Postal code<br />
</p>
<p><strong>Contact:</strong> Firstname Lastname, PH.D., P.ENG. - <a href="mailto:email@email.com">email@email.com</a><br /></p>
<a href="http://www.domain.com">www.domain.com</a><br />
<p><strong>Phone:</strong> (555)555-5555<br /></p>
```

So, I need to grab everything between Member Information and the last div tag then increment the ID value 1, repeat. BUT, there are a lot of dead IDs. My scraper just hammers the site, incrementing once then hitting it again. Is there an easier way? Perhaps some way to build a failsafe in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to tell whether an id exists until you try to load it and see whether it does. You'll need to find a list of links, or scrape member IDs from another part of the site. If you can't do that, you'll just have to try each one.

Comment: Gotcha. And how do I narrow my crawl to be within the code sample posted above? Right now it's grabbing the whole page. Thanks!

Comment: how do you load the page? you might be able to just read 1kB at a time, and once you've processed all you need, you can close the connection without reading the rest. you will have to read sequentially up to the relevant portion, though.

Comment: do you do a `.read()`? if so, try doing `.read(1024)` at a time

Comment: I do. That hadn't occurred to me. Thanks!

Comment: Check out scraperwiki.com for plenty of examples and help on how to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make HEAD requests. Skip the 404's and do GET's with the good ones. Forget about read(1024), that will waste your bandwidth and theirs.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no 404's. Just a 'Unable to retrieve client information.' message but no error. I guess I could just filter those out but I don't know of any other way to look for that.

Comment: Try the content-length header. It will be available in HEAD requests.